# ios - different section with different cell.accessoryType

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have table with two sections, I want first section cells to have indicator, and second section cells no indicator.

I tried this:

```
    if (indexPath.section==1){

             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }else if(indexPath.section==2){

             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

and this:

```
   if(indexPath.section==1){

        switch(indexPath.row){

            default:
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

                break;

        }

    }else if(indexPath.section==2){

        switch(indexPath.row){

            default:
               cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

                break;

        }

    }
```

None worked with me, what did i do wrong?

Comment: Try to NSLog the indexPath.section and see what number you have. Otherwise your top code looks good it should work.

Answer (score 4):

The index of the first section should be `0`, not `1`.
The index of the second section should be `1`, not `2`.

Remember that in (most) programming languages we are indexing from zero.

Comment: even though, I still have the same problem

Comment: @weky Then I would recommend you to add more code because there is no other bug in those 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

do you use the same cell identifier? Did you try two different cell identifiers?
Try to use 2 different one.